# Accessing the (linux) task_struct structure

Tags: c, linux, gcc

The Linux *task_struct* structure is defined in the  header and is wrapped in preprocessor macros

```
#ifndef KERNEL


struct task_struct{

....

....

};


...

...

#endif
```

Now there are functions in other headers that take task_struct objects as parameters in their argument list but I always get a compiler error in gcc that task_struct is undefined.
So in short, can headers which functions and data structures that use task structs only be compiled and with kernel compile(as part of a kernel object)? Or is there a way to compile them using the classic gcc c-compile command?

Comment: You can't access that struct from a user program. You need a module that is loaded into the kernel. You need root privs for that.

Comment: That's what I thought. And does the same go for compiler headers that use task_struct?